# Dllimport passing string from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, string, dllimport

I'm trying to pass a string from C# to C++, using platform invoke.

- C++ code:

  ```
  #include<string>
  using namespace std;

  extern "C" 
  {
       double __declspec(dllexport) Add(double a, double b)
       {
           return a + b;
       }
       string __declspec(dllexport) ToUpper(string s)
       {
           string tmp = s;
           for(string::iterator it = tmp.begin();it != tmp.end();it++)
               (*it)-=32;
           return tmp;
       }
  }
  ```
- C# code:

  ```
  [DllImport("TestDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention =CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  public static extern string ToUpper(string s); 

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      string s = "hello";
      Console.WriteLine(Add(a,b));
      Console.WriteLine(ToUpper(s));
  }
  ```

I receive a SEHException.  Is it impossible to use `std::string` like this? Should I use `char*` instead ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I suggest to use char*. Here a possible solution.

If you create another C# function ToUpper_2 as follows

C# side:

```
[DllImport("TestDll.dll"), CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl]
private static extern IntPtr ToUpper(string s);

public static string ToUpper_2(string s) 
{
    return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ToUpper(string s));
}
```

C++ side:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) const char* ToUpper(char* s) 
{
    string tmp(s);

    // your code for a string applied to tmp

    return tmp.c_str();
}
```

you are done!

Comment: Sorry for slow reply, but I copied your code into my project and have some weird syntax error ??

Comment: It work now but the string still remain the same after call that functions.Why does that happen ?

Comment: That's my mistake.It works now but the output string is not as I expected.I think it should be the uppercase of the original string ?

Comment: Don't know how but I get this error:cannot convert from 'const char *(__thiscall std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::* )(void) throw() const' to 'char *'.Btw are you sure about tmp.c_str(), I use VC++ 2012 and it give me syntax error and change it to tmp.c_str instead.

Comment: It's too late here and I feel so sleepy now so I think I'll comeback tomorrow.Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: Don't know how but I think the tmp.c_str() doesn't work like I want.It point to some random string, I edit ToUpper() function to return void and just copy tmp to s.Now it really works.

Comment: `return tmp.c_str();` will return garbage. `tmp` will get destroyed when `ToUpper` returns in C++. This answer is just bad.

Answer (score 1):

Сorrect decision

C# side:

```
[DllImport("CppDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr GetString(string s);

public string GetString_(string s)
{            
    var ptr = GetString(s);                                
    var answerStr = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
    return answerStr;
}
```

C++ side:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) const char* GetString(char* s)
{       
    string workStr(s);      
    int lenStr = workStr.length() + 1;
    char* answer = new char[lenStr];
    const char * constAnswer = new char[lenStr];
    strcpy(answer, workStr.c_str());
    constAnswer = answer;
    return constAnswer;
}
```

And disable /sdl- in the settings of the cpp project.

Comment: That is a memory leak, nobody is calling delete[].  Well, marginally better than the dangling pointer bug in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it without causing a memory leak is using a callback.

C# side:

```
private delegate bool DLLCallback(IntPtr message);
    
[DllImport(@"YourLibrary.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern void Receive(DLLCallback callback);
    
private static bool callback(IntPtr ptr)
{
    string result = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
        
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    // If the Heap is used               
    // Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return true;
}
        
private static void Main(string[] args)        {
    Receive(callback);
}
```

C++ side:

```
extern "C" {
   typedef BOOL(__stdcall* OutputCallback)(const char* str);

   __declspec(dllexport) void Receive(OutputCallback callback)
   {
        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
        ZeroMemory(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        BOOL callbackResult = callback(buffer);
   }
}
```

There are other options. This is a good article about passing strings between managed and unmanaged code: [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1189085/Passing-strings-between-managed-and-unmanaged-code)